# writing std::map in binary file which has value of struct type without boost

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include <fstream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
}stru;

int main()
{
    stru s;
    s.a = 1;
    s.b = 2;
    map<int, stru> m;
    m.insert(make_pair(22, s));
    ofstream os("test");
    int sizeOfStruct = sizeof(stru);
    std::map<int, stru>::iterator itr;
    for(itr = m.begin(); itr != m.end(); itr++)
    {
      os.write((char*)(&(itr->first)), sizeof(int));
      os.write((char*)(&sizeOfStruct), sizeof(int));
      os.write(itr->second, sizeOfStruct);
    }
}
```

for this code i am getting following error :

```
mapOnfile.cc: In function ?int main()?: mapOnfile.cc:29: error: no
matching function for call to ?std::basic_ofstream<char,
std::char_traits<char> >::write(stru&, int&)?
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.1.2/../../../../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/ostream.tcc:483:
note: candidates are: std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&
std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::write(const _CharT*,
std::streamsize) [with _CharT = char, _Traits =
std::char_traits<char>]
```

Please help me , how to save this type of map in binary file
map

**Please don't give any Boost serialization answer.**

Comment: Even when you fix the build errors, that code won't work. You can't write a `std::string` object to a file, and then load it from another process. A `std::string` object have the length of the contained string, plus a *pointer* to a C-style string, pointing to the actual "string". The problem is that pointers are really unique per process. A pointer to dynamically allocated data in one process is unlikely to point anywhere valid in another process, even if it's the same program being rerun. You have to [*serialize*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) the string object.

Comment: As for your problem, read the error message a little closer, and ask yourself why you cast the first argument to `write` in two calls, but not the third? Maybe you need to read [a `ostream::write` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write)?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg removed string object from structure. Main question here is how to put map in file whose value is type of structure.

Comment: Why not write a function that serialises the *struct* for you?